# no access to m3u8 when using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I have a code that allows me to download videos from `.m3u8`, but for some reason it hasn't worked since yesterday

```
ffmpeg -user_agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" -headers "Referer: https://upstream.to/" -i "https://s92.upstreamcdn.co/hls2/01/03509/wc3i5yhdfgyk_o/master.m3u8?t=M9p8oTpo_LgYLnh2Ay4UEOT6Szltp5vGepiZ09ZjnFo&s=1696668614&e=10800&f=17548793&i=169.150&sp=0" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "name.mp4"
```

what can I do to make it similar to the upstream task which looks like this

```
Request URL:https://s92.upstreamcdn.co/hls2/01/03509/wc3i5yhdfgyk_o/master.m3u8?t=M9p8oTpo_LgYLnh2Ay4UEOT6Szltp5vGepiZ09ZjnFo&s=1696668614&e=10800&f=17548793&i=169.150&sp=0
Request Method: GET
Status Code:    200 OK
Remote Address: 164.132.163.19:443
Referrer Policy:    strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    *
Cache-Control:  max-age=8640000
Cache-Control:  public, no-transform
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Content-Type:   application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Date:   Sat, 07 Oct 2023 08:50:16 GMT
Expires:    Mon, 15 Jan 2024 08:50:16 GMT
Last-Modified:  Sat, 07 Oct 2023 08:50:16 GMT
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:keep-alive
Host:s92.upstreamcdn.co
Origin:https://upstream.to
Referer:https://upstream.to/
Sec-Ch-Ua:"Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:cross-site
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: IS there a firewall blocking ffmpeg?